# Автоматический запуск

Tags: bat

Доброго времени суток, имею короткий интерес

Не сталкивался и не занимался батниками, но, нужно запускать левые файлы n-го расширения в определенной директории, правым софтом, который тоже соответственно располагается в своем краю, можете ли пояснить с примером как оно будет выглядеть и работать? 
Нужен bat для автоматизации запуска разного количества файлов но одним конкретным софтом

Answer (score 1):

`proga.exe` открывает `file.hz`

```
"C:\Program Files\MegaRightSoft\proga.exe" D:\files\myleftfiles\file.hz
```

Comment: в этом случае само по себе нужно будет переписывать все для каждого файла, как организовать цикл для выполнения этого действия для множества файлов